# regex for c++11 issue

Tags: regex, c++11

I have following string that I am working with

```
Ihwgiuwgdv {str{anything incl symb} chr{anything inc. symb} } blah blah
```

Using regex_search and regex_match I m looking for string starting from first brace to end brace.

I have tried

```
regex("\{[ ]*(str|chr)[ ]*\{(.)*\}[ ]*(str|chr)[ ]*\{(.)*\}[ ]*\}");
```

Notes: chr and str can swap positions but can't be both at the same time. Can have spaces as many as possible. Can't use boost I am using c++11. This regex (except (.)*) works with us but can't get the whole thing to work for c++

Comment: Are you using `std::regex`? if so are you using `libstdc++` which is the std library that ships with `g++`?  If so, then you can't do regex, it's not implemented.

Comment: Yes I was using it with g++ but after I read your comment I tried on VC++ 2012 with no success. OH NOTE, I replaced \{ with \\{ and { but no luck!

Comment: Can't you make blah blah something specific or in other ways put the end brace on the end of the string/line?

Answer (score 0):

Because [regular expressions were designed to match regular grammars.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Language)  And this is not strictly speaking a regular grammar.  It's going to be impossible to do simply with a regex. You can make it work but only by laboriously specifying both complete possibilities (version for str then chr and the other way around).  Or use a shortcut to ensure that both `\bstr\b` and `\bchr\b` exist in the string, and hope that whatever is inside of the inner braces doesn't trigger a false positive.

Or you can write a parser for this.  I would suggest that.  This looks quite a bit like JSON, you could probably rewrite an existing JSON parser simply, they're not complicated.

Comment: I love JSONs and have previously used json-cpp but I cannot use json because this is the only thing I want to parse and I dont want to import whole library for this. I have ended up writing my own little parser